# Is Nagato an Uchiha or an Uzumaki?

Tags: naruto

Is Nagato an Uchiha or an Uzumaki? I don't know - I am asking this question because their names sound alike and Nagato has red hair like Kushina Uzumaki.

Comment: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nagato says Uzumaki

Comment: His trademark red uzumaki hair turned white - Tobi/Obito when he was retrieving the RInnegan

Comment: Thx I had a feelin about that

Comment: He is a GOD ! !

Comment: Lol thnx I thought pain was a god

Comment: First: it was stated many times throughout the anime/manga that he is an Uzumaki. Second: Obito and Nagato buth were performing the reincarnation technique when their hair turned white. it is not becouse of retrieving the rinnegan but because of using it. Third Nagato is Pain. He controls all the pain members through chakra.

Answer (score 1):

He is an Uzumaki Bloodline.
He has the characteristics of an Uzumaki.

Red hair is what distinguishes them from the rest of the clans.

Uzumaki Naruto is different because his hair us a combination of yellow and red hair ( Minato x Kushina ) = Orangy - Yellow .